# Windows Explorer file order in the clipboard

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, clipboard

In my application I want to read files from Windows clipboard, and I want to see its in the same order, as I see this files in the Windows Explorer. E.g. if I ordered files alphabetically, I want to see its alphabetically ordered it the clipboard. But it turns out that Windows Explorer do it not quite perfectly.

Files actually ordered in the clipboard as desired, but with cyclical shift. I mean if correct order is 1-2-3-4-5-6-7, actual order may be 7-1-2-3-4-5-6 or 6-7-1-2-3-4-5 or 2-3-4-5-6-7-1 or 3-4-5-6-7-1-2 (I have seen different cases - sometimes it shifted one position, and sometimes it shifted two).

I thought it could be bug in my application, but FreeClipboardViewer shown the same. So I think it's some bug in Windows Explorer. Is there exist some workaround or something? Any information will be helpful.

I attached two examples - [alphabetically ordered files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfaag.png) and [files ordered by size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkDc9.png). Both shifted two position compared with original order.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You right click and copy the first file you right clicked on. If that does not suit you, as it was designed for users not programmers, sort it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just happen to remember this, can't take credit for "discovery", but quick testing says it still works.

The way/order in which you select the files matters. If you ***select the last one first***, and then use any of the common <kbd>Shift</kbd>|<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Arrow</kbd>|<kbd>MouseClick</kbd> methods to select the remainder, the files appear in the displayed sort order.

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you. I also discovered, that element selected when I press Ctrl+A also matters. If I select 444.txt and then press Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C, I got list like 4-5-6-7-1-2-3. There are some additional curious patterns - if I select files by Ctrl+Click, then selecting in random order produces normal 1-2-3-4-5-6-7 list, but selecting 4-5-6-7-1-2-3 produces 3-4-5-6-7-1-2 list, and selecting 4-3-2-1-7-6-5 produces 5-6-7-1-2-3-4 list. Most curious indeed.

Comment: There is nothing curious. It starts with the item that has **focus**.

Comment: **Focus** is the item keystrokes will go to. There will be a faint dotted line around it.